# Pose Library preview Material-Less

Tags: pose-mode

I am using Blender 3.0 and Creating my first pose Library. While saving poses i see that preview images of poses in blender 3.0 does not show colorful image for my poses. I have searched on Youtube but could not find a relevant solution. So, here i am asking if there is any setting to save render preview image in pose library. Or how to force blender to pick up render view version for pose library preview.
Here is Example
[image]

Answer (score 4):

Blender 3.0 [uses the workbench render engine](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/armatures/posing/editing/pose_library.html#controlling-the-look-of-preview-images) to render the pose library previews, so to get color in your preview thumbnails all you need to do is make sure workbench is set to output color.

So, for example:

- Open the Render properties tab.
- Change "Render Engine" menu selection
  to "Workbench"
- Under "Color" tab, choose "Texture"
- Re-generate the
  thumbnail using "Generate Preview" (circular double-arrows icon) in
  the N-panel of the asset browser.

You can switch the Render Engine back to Cycles or Eevee if you want, and Blender will still use the display settings you've chosen for workbench behind-the-scenes, so to speak, for thumbnail previews.

Also, Blender uses the active camera for this render, which isn't necessarily the angle shown in the active viewport, a behavior which might not be obvious at first.

Comment: It only picks random color option for other options Re-generate preview does not give textured/colored preview. Must be something more with my settings

Comment: Not sure why they decided on workbench for these thumbnails. So much of my work relies on procedural node-based texturing, and workbench does a bad job choosing what color those materials should be. I wonder if blender is aware myself and others are unhappy about this?

Comment: @Tyler I mean, it’s open source, so you could theoretically fix it yourself.  Realistically though, I know not everyone’s a programmer, so it’s more about convincing the people who are to make a change.

Comment: @JasonConrad yep! I've actually almost finished implementing the change in my own branch. I'll be submitting it for a merge request with the source for the devs to review soon.

Comment: @Tyler what change did you make on your branch? for the thumbnail to work using eevee material preview? I too, heavily use procedural materials on my assets and would love for my thumbnails to have colour without messing around with the object colour viewport display thing.